# Quotient of Quotient Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quotient-group

Say I have $N_1$ a normal subgroup of $G$, $N_2$ a normal subgroup of $G/N_1$, $N_3$ a normal subgroup of $((G/N_1)/N_2)$, ... $N_r$  normal subgroup of $((((G/N_1)/N_2)/N_3)/ ... )/N_{r-1}$.  What does the identity element of $((((G/N_1)/N_2)/N_3)/ ... )/N_r$ look like in coset notation of G?  What does a general element of that group look like?  I'm looking for an analogy to $G/N_1 = \{gN_1 | g \in G\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity is $e\cdot N_1\cdot....\cdot N_k$ and a general element looks like $g\cdot N_1\cdot...\cdot N_k$.

Warning: Since $N_1,N_2,...,N_k$ are subgroups of the different groups one can't talk about their product and therefore it is important to read the terms above with the brackets. It should be:

$$(...(((gN_1)N_2)N_3)...N_k)$$

Comment: But $N_1, N_2, \ldots$ are subgroups of different groups, so how are you forming the product $N_1 \cdot N_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot N_k$?

Comment: @RobArthan good question! I edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: That's right: $gN_1$ is the $G$-product of an element and a subset of $G$ and is set of subsets of $G$, then $(gN_1)N_2$ is the $G/N_1$-product of an element and a subset of $G/N_1$ and is set of sets of subsets of $G$ and so on.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses!

Comment: Your (Rob's) description finally made me understand the concept.  Element of the set and subset of the set so on and so forth. :)

Comment: My pleasure again. Did you know that you can smile in MathJax $\ddot{\smile}$?

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to Yanko's answer, note that an element of $(\ldots((G/N_1)/N_2)/N_3 \ldots /N_{r-1})/N_r$ is an element of the $r$-fold iterated power set, $\Bbb{P^r}G$. I.e., it is a set of sets of sets of ... of subsets of $G$ with $r+1$ "of"s. If
$$\pi_i: (\ldots((G/N_1)/N_2)/N_3 \ldots /N_{i-2})/N_{i-1} \to (\ldots((G/N_1)/N_2)/N_3 \ldots /N_{i-1})/N_i$$
is the natural projection, $i = 1, \ldots r$, then by $r$ applications of the [third isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2) $(\pi_{r} \circ \cdots \circ \pi_1)^{-1}[N_r]$ is a normal subgroup $K_r$ say of $G$ containing $N_1$ and $(\ldots((G/N_1)/N_2)/N_3 \ldots /N_{r-1})/N_r$ is naturally isomorphic to $G/K_r$ (whose elements are easier to represent, if you really need to know what the representation is, which is rare).

Comment: (+1) I think that this is the analogue the OP was looking for. It means that a general element looks like $gK_r$ where $K_r = (\pi_{r} \circ \cdots \circ \pi_1)^{-1}[N_r]$